# What is the name of this graph/plot?

Tags: biostatistics

[image]

What is the name of this graph/plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [Circos plot](http://circos.ca/), often used for visualizing genomic data, but works equally well for migration and some other applications.

Comment: Circos is a software package, and is capable of producing other graphic forms, such as concentric circles.

Comment: And there are other software packages that can produce these graphs, like the R-package circlize

Comment: Ah, yes you are correct. I've only ever heard them referred to as Circos plots colloquially, regardless of the software used to produce them, but thanks for correcting me!

Answer (score 6):

I think it is **Chord Diagram**. you can see [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GOplot/vignettes/GOplot_vignette.html#display-of-the-relationship-between-genes-and-terms-gochord) for more information.

> "A chord diagram is a graphical method of displaying the inter-relationships between data in a matrix. The data are arranged radially around a circle with the relationships between the data points typically drawn as arcs connecting the data." [based on the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_diagram)